# Javascript, set id attribute to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a module where I have an object and I append some elements depending how long is that object.
Now I want to set different ID's for all elements.

Here's my code:

```
Items.map(item =>{

var ParentDiv = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
var headerH1 = document.createElement('h1')
headerH1.setAttribute('id','header1')
ParentDiv.appendChild(headerH1);

})
```

What I have tried:

```
for(var i=0;i<=50;i++)
{
    headerH1.setAttribute('id','header'+i)
    ParentDiv.appendChild(headerH1);
}
```

I thought this would work but it just appends 50 elements but their ID will all be the same, "header50".

Can you tell me what am I missing me? Much appreciated.

Comment: To solve the issue in your question, you need to call `createElement()` ***within*** your loop, other wise you just create 1 element and clone it 50 times while updating the reference to it. However, more importantly, *never* use `id` attributes for repeated content. Use a common `class` which is the same for all generated elements. You can target them using DOM traversal methods based on the element which raises the required event handler.

Comment: To simply state it. You are only creating one node and moving it around by calling `appendChild`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `createElement` represents its own DOM element, and you need to interact with each element independently:

```js
const parentDiv = document.getElementById('parentDiv');

Items.forEach((item, i) => {
  const newItem = document.createElement('h1');
  newItem.setAttribute('id', `header${i}`);
  parentDiv.appendChild(newItem);
});
```

Also, while not required, I switched your `map` to a `forEach` since `map` should really only be used to create a new list, not as a function to just iterate over a list, which is what `forEach` is for.

Also, it's 2023, [use `let`/`const` instead of `var`](https://www.developer.com/languages/javascript/javascript-var-let-const-variable-declaration/) :)

Comment: Using map non-semantically is one of my pet peeves.

Comment: Thank you very much, it really helped me out! 
As for var, it's just a habit haha. Thank you once again.